# Closing multiple batch files

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

First time poster so hope I get this right.

I am trying to set up a batch file that first reads in the current date and time and makes a folder from it as below:

```
@echo off
SET dirname="%date:~0,2%-%date:~3,2%-%date:~6,4%-%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%"
mkdir Bat\%dirname%
attrib +s +h %dirname% /s /d
```

Following this I pull some backups in to the folder and then want to zip it with 7zip command line and have added this line to the first batch file:

```
start /wait Bat\7Zip.bat %dirname% Bat\%dirname%* -r
```

which calls 7zip.bat which is here:

```
@echo off
Bat\7z.exe a -mhe -p*** Bat\%dirname%.7z Bat\%dirname%* -r
exit 0
```

finally I try to delete the original folder using:

```
start /wait del /F /Q /a Bat\%dirname%
exit 0
```

Here are my two problems. First off, when it runs the 7zip file, after it completes, the second command prompt stays open, when I close this manually the first prompt asks if I want to abort the batch job even though its finished. I would like it all to just close on its own.

Second off. The del command works in so far as it deletes the files in the folder but not the folder itself, any ideas what I am missing?

Thanks in advance for all the help. Sorry this is one of my first batch attempts so is probably very sloppy.

Comment: Why do you need 7zip.bat? Just call 7z.exe with proper parameters instead of calling 7zip.bat. Also, why do you use 'start /wait' instead of 'call'? 'Call' looks simplier in this situation.

Comment: I initially had it in there, but tried to create the batch file in an attempt to close the window. Will add it back the way it was. Thanks. Also, I am teaching myself here and the wait command was the first I came too. Will look at call as well. Thanks.

Comment: Did Endoro's answer help you?

Comment: No, I was left with the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
SET "dirname=%date:~0,2%-%date:~3,2%-%date:~6,4%-%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%"
mkdir "Bat\%dirname%"
Bat\7z.exe a -mhe -p*** "Bat\%dirname%.7z" "Bat\%dirname%*" -r
RD /S /Q "Bat\%dirname%"
exit 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but still the same issue as before :( The script works but does not close :(

Comment: Do you use a shortcut to start the script?

Comment: No, I have saved it as a .bat file and just double click it to start it.

Comment: you mean 'double click'  in the Windows explorer?

Comment: Yes, and the batch works, doing it that way. It just doesn't close properly.

Answer (score 0):

Answer on second question about directory removement:
after `del /F /Q /a Bat\%dirname%` you have to call `rmdir Bat\%dirname%`

Answer (score 0):

from `start /help`

> command/program
>               If it is an internal cmd command or a batch file then
>               the command processor is run with the /K switch to cmd.exe.
>               This means that the window will remain after the command
>               has been run.
>
> ```
>         If it is not an internal cmd command or batch file then
>         it is a program and will run as either a windowed application
>         or a console application.
> ```

so you should use `start /wait Bat\7z.exe [...]` instead of `start /wait Bat\7Zip.bat [...]`

regarding the dir removal use `RD /S /Q [drive:]path` (use with caution)

Comment: OK I have updated to start /wait Bat\7z.exe a -mhe -p*** Bat\%dirname%.7z Bat\%dirname%* -r however I am still left with the second command box staying up as above...